# turn data off, on android Samsung note 4

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-4

what should I do,not to use up my data limit on my Samsung note 4,
what steps I need to know to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To turn off mobile data:

- Pull down the notifications bar, Find the *Mobile data* icon in
  Notification bar.
- Toggle OFF Mobile Data icon so that it is no longer green.

To set a limit:

- Settings → Data Usage → Set Mobile Data Limit
- Also on the same Data Usage screen you may want to press the action overflow icon on the top right and choose *Restrict Background Data*